# How can I get the default color of a list separator in Android in order to use it in a shape?

Tags: android, listview, colors, shapes

The question already says it: How can I get the default color of the list separator so that I can use it a shape like this:

```
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

I would to use the color instead of `#FFCCCCCC` in the stroke color.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
 android:divider="#FFCCCCCC"
```

to change color of listview seperator

2) to change the shape or make custom dividers, you can add a custom element in the row.xml of listview items. make sure to turn off dividers in this scenario.

3) If you have a drawable you want to use as divider you can set it programatically with:

```
list.setDivider(Drawable divider)
```

Comment: but I would like to use the default list separator color and not `#FFCC00

Comment: Where did you get that colour from?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the default color of the list separator

First, there are multiple default list dividers, based on theme. `Theme.Holo` has one, `Theme.Holo.Light` has one, `Theme.Material` has one, etc.

Second, particularly in the case of `Theme.Material`, the divider might be tinted based on theme attributes (e.g., accent color).

Third, the divider is not a simple color, but rather is a nine-patch PNG file. If you go into `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/platform-NN/data/res/drawable-XXXX/`, you will find them in the files beginning with `list_divider_`. In the above path, `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you installed your Android SDK, `NN` is some API level for an SDK platform that you downloaded, and `XXXX` is a density (e.g., `hdpi`).